# How do I scale and center an inline SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a `<div>` container of variable width, and also a `<svg>` of variable size contained within it.

The div is variable because it is based on window size. The svg is variable because it is defined by user input.

I'd like to scale the SVG such that it is entirely visible within the containing div, without the div cropping the svg, or with excess whitespace. Is there a method to do this?

Thank you very much!

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5zq0bhu7/1/

Comment: did you try: display: flex

Comment: @tech2017 on which element? Adding them to either doesn't appear to change anything

Comment: pls share your html, css

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle example to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're likely looking for is the [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) property, which defines the bounds of your graphic and how it scales within its container.  You can call [`svg.getBBox()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) to get the rough size of the internal paths of the SVG.

Here is the result:

```js
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");

// Get internal size of SVG
var bbox = svg.getBBox();

// Construct and set a viewBox for the SVG
var viewBox = [bbox.x, bbox.y, bbox.width, bbox.height].join(" ");

svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
```

```html
<div id="drawing" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <!-- width and height will vary in the application, but are defined here for debugging purposes -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <g fill="none" stroke="#000">
            <path stroke-width=".26458" d="M8.134 1.4a13.23 13.23 0 0 1 10.006 0M12.852.417a.285.285 0 1 1 .57 0 .285.285 0 1 1-.57 0M22.4 4.202a13.23 13.23 0 0 1 3.964 9.188M20.13 6.882a3.44 3.44 0 1 1 2.725 6.32 3.44 3.44 0 1 1-2.726-6.32m6.234 6.508" />
            <path stroke-width=".26458" d="M25.81 17.44a13.23 13.23 0 0 1-.017.057 6.216 6.216 0 1 0-8.076 8.56 13.23 13.23 0 0 1-.056.02M23.64 22.7a.622.622 0 1 1-.853.903.622.622 0 1 1 .853-.904m-5.977 3.378" />
            <path stroke-width=".26458" d="M12.624 26.866a13.23 13.23 0 0 1-.058-.003A6.216 6.216 0 1 0 2.26 21.177a13.23 13.23 0 0 1-.033-.048" />
            <path stroke-width=".26458" d="M.208 16.447a13.23 13.23 0 0 1-.013-.057A6.216 6.216 0 1 0 3.13 4.992a13.23 13.23 0 0 1 .04-.044" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

It's entirely visible in the container, and does not get cropped.  Excess whitespace is aggressively scaled off.  Here's a quick rundown of each property  that is set:

- `viewBox` to control the container scaling, dynamically generated with the call to `getBBox()`
- `width` and `height` to force the graphic to fill its container
- `preserveAspectRatio` to `none` to allow the SVG to scale to fit any container - remove this property to enforce the same aspect ratio - the SVG will instead fill the largest available dimension by default.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. My issue is that the SVG is generated by user input and its size can vary. I can't ask every user of my app to download the data, run it through Inkscape, and then reupload. Is there a way I can automate this process, or will I just have to standardise the sizes?

Comment: @snazzybouche Good point - missed that part of the original question.  I have updated my answer to handle *most* SVGs - it works on the original one in your question.

Comment: Woah, didn't know that was a thing - thank you so much! Do you know what kinds of SVG it won't work for?

Comment: @snazzybouche The SVG format itself is extremely complicated, and there are numerous ways to move things around unintuitively.  The [W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) I linked mentions bounding boxes not taking several things into account - namely strokes.  For example, if an SVG has a 10x10 rect with a 5px stroke, `getBBox()` will report the width/height as `10` instead of `20`.  Although there's [all sorts of crazy voodoo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kredit/dLryc9mz/) possible in SVG - `getBBox()` should be fine for 90% of cases.

Comment: Heh, fair enough. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the `.getBBox()` tip; I just used this inside a "general drawing" with Highcharts to detect the current container size.. Works like a charm with Highcharts 5 SVGs. :)